# Google Analytics without Javascript

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I thought I saw something a few months ago that allowed you to send GA requests without using Javascript (i.e. on server side).

We have some RSS feeds that we would like to track using GA, but for obvious reasons we can't without the use of Javascript.

This is for an ASP.Net site.

Comment: Actually, what do you want to track ?
Display / page views of the RSS Feed ?
Click on links in the RSS Feed ? 
How the RSS Feed drives audience to your site (which volume of audience it brings) ?

Comment: My customer just wants to know how many clicks really, no. of subscribers would also be a bonus (although not sure if that's possible).

Comment: What about counting visits coming from the rss feed instead of clicks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine you can use the Mobile code - there's an ASP.NET example in there:

[Google Analytics for Mobile](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/)

Comment: It's close, but it obviously requires a HTML page to execute, so I don't think this is going to help for RSS feeds, I guess something like FeedBurner will have to be used.  Thanks though :-)

Comment: @Mantorok: Could you not output the image in your feed XML?  I suppose that'll only work for feed readers that support images.  There's another option [here](http://www.mjdigital.co.uk/blog/track-xml-or-server-side-files-using-google-analytics/) (using a redirect) but it's PHP.

Comment: @Mantorok Not it dos not need any html to execure. See the asp.net part, you just make a web call from code behind with your parametres

Comment: @Aristos, I checked out the ASP.Net example and it tells you to embed it into an image tag in the html.

Comment: @Aristos: Mantorok is correct, it doesn't require JavaScript but it _does_ require an HTML `<img>` tag.

Comment: @Town @Mantorok Yes you can connect it to an image to pass parametres, but you can add this parametres manual or with other simple code inside the code. The image html is used only to pass parametres.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GoogleAnalyticsTracker](https://github.com/maartenba/GoogleAnalyticsTracker), which works for asp.net (also available via NuGet). I also did a [quick port for windows phone](http://codecube.net/2012/02/googleanalyticstracker-for-windows-phone/) as well, if you're interested in that.

Answer (score 1):

When you know what url you should use for the image, you can call the image directly and send the same data. You need to be able to request the image url.

The [link here](http://www.vdgraaf.info/google-analytics-without-javascript.html) claims to have implemented this but this example given are of PHP. Just check if you can apply the logic in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a non-javascript version of GA, though it's not impossible to do, it will take some extensive server side scripting to create/manage cookies, and generate the appropriate calls to __utm.gif for pageviews and transactions.

If you're up to the challenge, you can use Firebug (for Firefox) to get the exact URL to /_utm.gif and try to recreate them.